# Twitter External Login callback failing with certificate error on azure cloud service deployment

Tags: oauth-2.0, ssl-certificate, twitter-oauth, owin, azure-cloud-services

I have an MVC5 application where I have enabled external login providers in google, facebook and twitter. I have created my apps on each of the respective sites and obtained the app ids and secret keys. I have tested these on localhost and all was working as expected.

I then deployed my site to http:.net but upon logging in with my twitter account I am getting the following error:

**Exception information: 
    Exception type: WebException 
    Exception message: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
   at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)**

I have gotten a 90 day free SSL cert from Comodo and included this in my personal store on the IIS server. Google, facebook and Microsoft are working without issue

Comment: Anyone had similar problem?